# How many cases of this event?(derangement)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

There are $4$ different stuff of the people A,B,C and D. After the inspector gathered and checked their things, He is now distributing the stuff to the each person. Find the case having only exactly 1 person receiving his own's stuff.

My soultion is

$\binom{4}{1} \cdot 3!$ : The cases for $1$ person receives his stuff.

$\binom{4}{2} \cdot 2!$ : The cases for $2$-person receive his stuff.

$\binom{4}{3} \cdot 1!$ : The cases for $3$-person receive his stuff.

$\binom{4}{4} \cdot 0!$ : The cases for $4$-person receive his stuff.

Therefore, $\binom{4}{1} \cdot 3! -\binom{4}{2} \cdot 2!+\binom{4}{3} \cdot 1!-\binom{4}{4} \cdot 0!=15 $  by the inclusion-extension principle.

But the answer was $8$. I can't find my mistakes in my solution. Please Let me know my missing point. Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean $\binom{4}{3}1!$ for the case that three people each receive their stuff?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig. yes. That was the typo. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is one of **partial** derangements.

There are $4$ choices for the person who gets his stuff, say $A$ gets it.

Now, $B,C,D$ must *not* get their stuff.

Since you apparently know about derangements, and a (full) derangement of three is easily seen to be $2$,

ans $=4\cdot2 = 8$

You can look up [partial derangements](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialDerangement.html#:%7E:text=distinct%2C%20ordered%20items%20in%20which,2002%2C%20p.) for an understanding of how to compute for any such problem